# Python Blackjack Game how to carry a variable in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm still deep into the making of my Blackjack game in Python, my aim is to allow the computer to 'twist' (Take another card) until the total value is greater than 15. From then onwards I want it so that as the total of the cards gets higher, the chance of the computer taking another card gets smaller just like a human (taking a risk if the number isn't TOO big).The following code occurs after the computer has been dealt two values.

`if (computerCardValueTotal < 15):
            print ("The computer has decided to twist")
            ranCompCard3 = random.choice(availableCards)
            computerCardValueTotal = ranCompCard + ranCompCard2 + ranCompCard3
            if (computerCardValueTotal < 15):
                print ("The computer has chosen to twist again")`

My aim is to have this piece of code loop if the total value is less than 15 so that the computer twists until it is over 15. I have considered using a while loop but I'm unsure on how to carry the current total to the start of the loop so that the next card value is added to the current total. Does anyone have a solution they could help me out with?

Also, secondly, it's not the biggest of the two issues in this question, but how would you recommend doing the computer so that the chance of it twisting again is smaller as the total value of cards get bigger? For example, for if the value of the cards totals at 17, there's a 1/10 chance of the computer twisting but if the total value of the cards is 19 the chance of the computer twisting is 1/20.

All valuable help will be voted up and as always, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hobbled yourself by making e.g. `ranCompCard`, `ranCompCard2`, `ranCompCard3`, ... when a `list` would make life much easier:

```
compCards = [ranCompCard, ranCompCard2]
while sum(compCards) < 15:
    compCards.append(random.choice(availableCards))
```

---

For adjusting the probability of picking another card, you could do something like:

```
while True:
    gap = 21 - sum(compCards)
    if gap > 0 and random.random() < (1 / (40 / float(gap))):
        compCards.append(random.choice(availableCards))
    else:
        break
```

Note that this is a linear relationship between `gap` and the probability of picking another card:

```
>>> for card_sum in range(15, 21):
    print card_sum, 1 / (40 / float(21 - card_sum))


15 0.15
16 0.125
17 0.1
18 0.075
19 0.05
20 0.025
```

but you can adjust the equation as needed.

---

While you're editing your code, take a look at (and consider following) the [official style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); variable names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.

Comment: Wouldn't that just replace compCards with a random of availableCards or would it add it? Haven't used append before.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the style guide. I was about to do the saem in a comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi John, sorry to bring this post up after just under 2 weeks. Is there any chance you could briefly explain the technicalities behind the 'gap' solution. Also, as the cards are **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Queen,King,Jack,Ace** the append solution wont work (don't worry, I'm not that stupid that I've let this go for nearly 2 weeks, I only really got back to my PC and realised the issue with the solution today). My intention is for the card names to remain until the end of the game so that it could say for example, 'The computer had a King a 2 and a 7'.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by *"technicalities"*? It's a fairly straightforward approach; is there some part of it in particular you don't understand? You can `append` any object to a list, so it's not clear what you mean by *"wont [sic] work"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my apologies regarding the duplicate post and also the fact I did not realise you had responded, the reply didn't show up. Let me review the answer again.

Comment: `shouldDealerDraw=lambda dealer_sum: random() < dict(zip(range(22),[1]*15+[0.8,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.01,0]))[int(dealer_sum)]
` might be more helpful than a formula for this but meh ... solid answer(+1)

Comment: @jonrsharpe with regards to the 'wont work' for example, say Card 1 is **Jack**, card 2 is **3** the total should be 13 but in fact it's Jack and 3. So the 'if less than 15 pick another' option was used, it wouldn't work because Jack is not a number. I already have a method of it converting the Jack/Queen/King into numbers but not sure how to use it in the loop append method. I think it would be better if the Jack/Queen/King were assigned values before hand but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @PythonBoy69 so how do you work out the value of the player's cards elsewhere? Just plug that code in here. At the simplest have two lists (`cards` and `card_values`), or consider implementing a `Card` class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is the solution to the non append solution, I'd copy and paste it into the comment but the formatting is horrible, so here's a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/csicaakvf/. As you can see, this solution would not work with the append solution as it is for `_card` and `_card2` meaning it would not work with `comp_cards`.

Comment: @PythonBoy69 I can only suggest you get to grips with [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), otherwise your code will continue to have significant unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks very much for the links, will read through the python docs and get back to you if I have any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reassign the value when it changes.

```
while computerCardValueTotal < 15:
  # other code
  computerCardValueTotal = <new value>
```